# elasticsearch filtering by the size of a field that is an array

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I filter documents that have a field which is an array and has more than N elements?

How can I filter documents that have a field which is an empty array?

Is facets the solution? If so, how?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I would have a look at the [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/script-filter.html). The following filter should return only the documents that have at least 10 elements in the `fieldname` field, which is an array. Keep in mind that this could be expensive depending on how many documents you have in your index.

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "doc['fieldname'].values.length > 10"
    }
}
```

Regarding the second question: do you really have an empty array there? Or is it just an array field with no value? You can use the [missing filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/missing-filter.html) to get documents which have no value for a specific field:

```
"filter" : {
    "missing" : { "field" : "user" }
}
```

Otherwise I guess you need to use scripting again, similarly to what I suggested above, just with a different length as input. If the length is constant I'd put it in the `params` section so that the script will be cached by elasticsearch and reused, since it's always the same:

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "doc['fieldname'].values.length > params.param1"
        "params" : {
            "param1" : 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you know how to do this if the field was a string and not an array? i tried `"script": "doc['title'].value.length() > 10"` but no luck ...

Comment: I have the same problem, the field is an array, but ES sees it as String, so that it throws `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: length for class: java.lang.String`

Comment: @lisak Try this: "script": "doc['fieldname'].size() > 50"

Comment: @david_adler I posted answer for that kind of problem (when field is text field). https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213332/1987830

Answer (score 18):

javanna's answer is correct on Elasticsearch 1.3.x and earlier, since 1.4 the default scripting module has changed to [groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) (was [mvel](http://mvel.codehaus.org/)).

To answer OP's question.

On Elasticsearch 1.3.x and earlier, use this code:

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "doc['fieldname'].values.length > 10"
    }
}
```

On Elasticsearch 1.4.x and later, use this code:

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "doc['fieldname'].values.size() > 10"
    }
}
```

Additionally, on Elasticsearch 1.4.3 and later, you will need to enable the dynamic scripting as it has been disabled by default, because of security issue. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/modules-scripting.html

Answer (score 10):

Still posting to here for who stuck same situation with me.
Let's say your data look like this:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "fieldName" : [
            {
                "f1": "value 11",
                "f2": "value 21"
            },
            {
                "f1": "value 12",
                "f2": "value 22"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then to filter `fieldName` with length > 1 for example:

```
"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "script" : {
                "script" : {
                    "inline": "doc['fieldName.f1'].values.length > 1",
                    "lang": "painless"
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script syntax is as ES 5.4 documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html.

Comment: `doc['fieldName.f1'].length > 2`  working fine on es 7.x

Answer (score 6):

Imho the correct way of filtering arrays by size using scripting is :

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "_source.fieldName.size() > 1"
    }
}
```

If I do that as @javanna suggests it throws exception `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: length for class: java.lang.String`

Comment: Source is much slower than doc, it hits disk.

Comment: Also, note that you've used `fieldName` and the others used `fieldname`.

Comment: The reason is that `Groovy` provides `size()` for both arrays and strings. If not _all_ of your values are arrays, then you will run into the issue that you did because you are trying to use a length _property_ on a String, which does not exist.

Comment: ```
"caused_by": {
     "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
     "reason": "Variable [_source] is not defined."
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have an array of ***objects*** that aren't mapped as `nested`, keep in mind that Elastic will flatten them into:

```
attachments: [{size: 123}, {size: 456}] --> attachments.size: [123, 456]
```

So you want to reference your field as `doc['attachments.size'].length`, not `doc['attachments'].length`, which is very counter-intuitive.

Same for `doc.containsKey(attachments.size)`.

The `.values` part is deprecated and no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this:
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableList.java?r=707f3a276d4ea8e9d53621d137febb00cd2128da

And on lisak's answer here.

There is size() function which returns the length of list:

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "doc['fieldname'].values.size() > 10"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do this is to "denormalize" your data so that you have a property that contains the count and a boolean if it exists or not. Then you can just search on those properties.

For example:

```
{
   "id": 31939,
   "hasAttachments": true,
   "attachmentCount": 2,
   "attachments": [
      {
         "type": "Attachment",
         "name": "txt.txt",
         "mimeType": "text/plain"
      },
      {
         "type": "Inline",
         "name": "jpg.jpg",
         "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
      }
   ]  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me:

```
GET index/search {
    "query": {
       "bool": {
          "filter" : {
             "script" : {
                "script" : "doc['FieldName'].length > 10"
                }
            }
         }
       }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For version 7+:

```
"filter": {
    "script": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['fieldName.keyword'].length > 10",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
    }
}
```

Ref. https://medium.com/@felipegirotti/elasticsearch-filter-field-array-more-than-zero-8d52d067d3a0

Answer (score 0):

When you need to find documents which contains some field which size/length should be larger then zero [@javanna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15548868/1987830) gave correct answer. I only wanted to add if your **field is text field** and you want to find documents which contains some text in that field you can't use same query. You will need to do something like this:

```
GET index/_search 
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "FIELD_NAME": {
                            "gt": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is not exact answer to this question because answer already exists but solution for similar problem which I had so maybe somebody will find it useful.

Comment: Which would be smarter to compute that at index time instead of having to compute that at search time which is going to be slow as it has to go through all the hits. Specifically if you have a match_all query.

Answer (score 0):

a suggestion about the second question:

> How can I filter documents that have a field which is an empty array?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "fieldname"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will return docs with empty `fieldname: []` arrays. `must` (rather than `must_not` will return the opposite).

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose our Array is an object like,

```
user: {
id: "01"
name: "Shikhil"
}
{
id: "02"
name: "Shankar"
}
```

We can aggregate the length using painless scripts

````
GET org-teams/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "anyId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_requirements": {
          "sum": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "params._source.containsKey('users') && params._source['users'] != null  ? params._source.users.size() : 0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````