# ElasticSearch Accessing Nested Documents in Script - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

Gist: Trying to write a custom filter on nested documents using painless. Want to write error checks when there are no nested documents to surpass `null_pointer_exception`

I have a mapping as such (simplified and obfuscated)

```
{
  "video_entry" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
       
        "captions_added" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "category" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
           
        "is_votable" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
      
        "members" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "country" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
            },
            "date_of_birth" : {
              "type" : "date",
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Each `video_entry` document can have 0 or more `members` nested documents.

Sample Document

```
{
   "captions_added": true,
   "category"      : "Mental Health",
   "is_votable:    : true,
   "members": [
        {"country": "Denmark", "date_of_birth": "1998-04-04T00:00:00"},
        {"country": "Denmark", "date_of_birth": "1999-05-05T00:00:00"}
   ]

}
```

If one or more nested document exist, we want to write some painless scripts that'd check certain fields across all the nested documents. My script works on mappings with a few documents but when I try it on larger set of documents I get null pointer exceptions despite having every null check possible. I've tried various access patterns, error checking mechanisms but I get exceptions.

```
POST /video_entry/_search
{
  "query": {
   "script": {
     "script": {
       "source": """
          // various NULL checks that I already tried
          // also tried short circuiting on finding null values
          if (!params['_source'].empty && params['_source'].containsKey('members')) {


              def total = 0;
          
          
              for (item in params._source.members) {
                // custom logic here
                // if above logic holds true 
                // total += 1; 
              } 
          
              return total > 3;
         }
         
         return true;
          
       """,
       "lang": "painless"
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Other Statements That I've Tried

```
if (params._source == null) {
    return true;
}

if (params._source.members == null) {
    return true;
}

if (!ctx._source.contains('members')) {
    return true;
}

if (!params['_source'].empty && params['_source'].containsKey('members') && 
     params['_source'].members.value != null) {
    
    // logic here

}

if (doc.containsKey('members')) {
  for (mem in params._source.members) {
  }

}
```

Error Message

```
&& params._source.members",
                 ^---- HERE"

 "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason" : null
          }
```

I've looked into changing the structure (flattening the document) and the usage of [must_not as indicated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867442/5698202). They don't suit our use case as we need to incorporate some more custom logic.

Different tutorials use `ctx`, `doc` and some use `params`. To add to the confusion `Debug.explain(doc.members)`, `Debug.explain(params._source.members)` return empty responses and I'm having a hard time figuring out the types.

---

Gist: Trying to write a custom filter on nested documents using painless. Want to write error checks when there are no nested documents to surpass `null_pointer_exception`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TLDr;

`Elastic` flatten objects. Such that

```
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [ 
    {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

Turn into:

```
{
  "group" :        "fans",
  "user.first" : [ "alice", "john" ],
  "user.last" :  [ "smith", "white" ]
}
```

To access `members` inner value you need to reference it using `doc['members.<field>']` as `members` will not exist on its own.

## Details

As you may know, `Elastic` handles inner documents in its own way. [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

So you will need to reference them accordingly.

Here is what I did to make it work.
Btw, I have been using the `Dev tools` of kibana

```
PUT /so_test/

PUT /so_test/_mapping
{
  "properties" : {
    "captions_added" : {
      "type" : "boolean"
    },
    "category" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "is_votable" : {
      "type" : "boolean"
    },
    "members" : {
      "properties" : {
        "country" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "date_of_birth" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /so_test/_doc/
{
   "captions_added": true,
   "category"      : "Mental Health",
   "is_votable"    : true,
   "members": [
        {"country": "Denmark", "date_of_birth": "1998-04-04T00:00:00"},
        {"country": "Denmark", "date_of_birth": "1999-05-05T00:00:00"}
   ]
}

PUT /so_test/_doc/
{
   "captions_added": true,
   "category"      : "Mental breakdown",
   "is_votable"    : true,
   "members": []
}

POST /so_test/_doc/
{
   "captions_added": true,
   "category"      : "Mental success",
   "is_votable"    : true,
   "members": [
        {"country": "France", "date_of_birth": "1998-04-04T00:00:00"},
        {"country": "Japan", "date_of_birth": "1999-05-05T00:00:00"}
   ]
}
```

And then I did this query (it is only a bool filter, but I guess making it work for your own use case should not prove too difficult)

```
GET /so_test/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": """
            def flag = false;
            
            // /!\ notice how the field is referenced /!\
            if(doc['members.country'].size() != 0)
            {
              for (item in doc['members.country']) {
                if (item == params.country){
                  flag = true
                }
              } 
            }
            return flag;
            """,
            "params": {
              "country": "Japan"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BTW you were saying you were a bit confused about the context for painless. you can find in the documentation so details about it.
[[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-contexts.html)

In this case the [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-filter-context.html) is the one we want to look at.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Really appreciate it. Gave it a whirl yesterday and it works. Will accept your answer in a bit :)

Comment: I glad it helped. ^^

Comment: One issue I'm facing is - Your example doesn't make `members` as nested. Running `GET /so_test` results in  "members" : {  "properties" : {  "country" : { "type" : "keyword" }, "date_of_birth" : { "type" : "date" } } } which indicates it isn't a Nested Object.

Comment: Your answer works with the object fields I have. Many thanks for that though :)

Comment: The mapping of a document, does reflect how the documents is ingested. But does not reflect how the document is indexed internally. I am myself not super clear about it. But that is what I understood. Painless will interact with the indexed version of the document, not the ingested one. Anyhow, glad it helped. Feel free to validate the answer.

Comment: Seems to be the case -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170005/5698202