# Elasticsearch filtering by array field size

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I have a collection in MongoDB with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "Name" : "A",
        "CustomerInfo" : [ 
            {
                "CustomerCompany" : "abc",
                "CustomerEmail" : "user1@abc.com",
                "SubmissionDate" : 1415070090
            }, 
            {
                "CustomerCompany" : "xyz",
                "CustomerEmail" : "user2@xyz.com",
                "SubmissionDate" : 1438820000
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name" : "B",
    },
    {
        "Name" : "C",
        "CustomerInfo" : [ 
            {
                "CustomerCompany" : "mno",
                "CustomerEmail" : "user3@mno.com",
                "SubmissionDate" : 1412590000
            }
        ]
    }
    ...
]
```

I created a river for this collection in elasticsearch using [Elasticsearch-river-plugin](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb)

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/product_custinfo/_meta' -d '{
  "index": {
    "name": "CustomerInfo",
    "type": "CustomerInfo"
  },
  "mongodb": {
    "db": "MyDB",
    "collection": "CustInfo"
  },
  "type": "mongodb"
}'
```

Mapping created by river:

```
"CustomerInfo" : {
    "properties" : {
        "CustomerCompany" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "CustomerEmail" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "SubmissionDate" : {
            "type" : "long"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to query documents that have more than 2 customers. (Note: It can be any value).
I was able to get the results in MongoDB using the following query:

```
db.CustInfo.find({'$where' : 'this.CustomerInfo.length > 2'})
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543308/elasticsearch-filtering-by-the-size-of-a-field-that-is-an-array) question, I tried this elasticsearch query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"exists" : {
                            "field" : "CustomerInfo"
                            }
                        },
                        {"script" : {
                            "script" : "doc['CustomerInfo'].size() > 2"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which resulted in this error:

> nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No field found for [CustomerInfo] in mapping with types []]];

Using `_source` instead of `doc` gives the correct result but is very slow.

```
"script" : {
    "script" : "_source.CustomerInfo.size() > 2"
}
```

Is there another way to filter the result based on array field size?
I don't want to create a new field with number of customers.

---

MongoDB : 3.0.7

ElasticSearch : 1.4.2

Elasticsearch-River-Plugin : 2.0.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `CustomerInfo` does not exist in Lucent, the fields that exist are `CustomerInfo.CustomerCompany`, `CustomerInfo.CustomerEmail` and `CustomerInfo.SubmissionDate`. So you can use `"script" : "doc['CustomerInfo.CustomerCompany'].size() > 2"`