# Retrieve length of an array field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

A field in an index I'm building gets regularly appended to. I'd like to be able to query elasticsearch to count the number of current items. Is it possible to query for the length of an array field? I can write something to bring back the field and count the items but some of them have a large number of entries and so am looking for something that is done in place in ES.

Comment: What kind of field is this? (string, numeric, date, analyzed, not_analyzed)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I recommend. Perform a terms aggregation over _uid. Then perform another aggregation over all the fields in the array field and sum the doc_counts.

But such an operation really depends on the number of records that you need to query otherwise, this can be an expensive operation.

Another option you have is to store count of array elements as another field and query it directly and given the fact that you are already storing large arrays in your document, having an integer field for the size seems to be a fair trade-off. In case you need the count to filter records I would recommend using scripted filter as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543308/elasticsearch-filtering-by-the-size-of-a-field-that-is-an-array)