# Query an Array of Objects to be an Exact Match in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-nested

Consider the following index

```
PUT /orchards
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "fruits": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "farms": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "visits": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "counts": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with these documents

```
POST orchards/_doc
{
  "fruits" : [
    {
    "farms" : 1,
    "visits" : 1,
    "counts" : [1]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
POST orchards/_doc
{
  "fruits" : [
    {
    "farms" : 1,
    "visits" : 1,
    "counts" : [1]
    },
    {
    "farms" : 2,
    "visits" : 2,
    "counts" : [1,2]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to write a query to only return the document having

```
"fruits" : [
    {
    "farms" : 1,
    "visits" : 1,
    "counts" : [1]
    }
  ]
```

I tried it by writing the following query

```
GET /orchards/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "fruits",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "fruits.counts": [
                  1
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "fruits.visits": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "fruits.farms": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the result hits contained both the documents i.e **it does not perform an exact match**.

I want to avoid comparing lengths using scripts because it's an expensive operation - as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543308/elasticsearch-filtering-by-the-size-of-a-field-that-is-an-array)

Tried some other variations as well, but they all seemed to give either no hits or both the documents as result.

References

[Query on Nested Type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

[Query on Array Type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html)

Comment: to get only matching  nested documents use inner_hits{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

This is the expected behaviour.
In the nested document, you got a match, so the whole document is returned.

If you are only interested in the information from the match you could use something like [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html)

## Solution

Notice the `_source: false` and the `inner_hits:{}`

```json
GET /orchards/_search
{
  "_source": "false", 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "fruits",
      "inner_hits": {},
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "fruits.counts": [
                  1
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "fruits.visits": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "fruits.farms": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the solution I was looking for;
can you also share the query for the case when we have multiple list of objects and we need an exact match for all of them e.g query for this doc http://p.ip.fi/G-Q8 using inner_hits